# Ionic correct redirect on app load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

When I first load the applications, its supposed to check if a user exits and then redirect to the correct page.

In app.js I added the following code:

```
if ($localStorage.currentUser) {
    $state.go('homePage');
} 
else {
    $state.go('loginPage');
}
```

and in routes.js I added the following code at the end

```
if (window.localStorage['ngStorage-currentUser']) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/homePage');
}
else {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/loginPage'); 
}
```

but what happens is, if there is no user, it loads the homePage for a few moments before loading the loginPage. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to hook your fi else statement into the `$routeChangeStart` which will fire before the page is loaded . you can more more information on the route life cycle events [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

You could also use the `.run` in your `app` file

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
     var $state = $injector.get("$state");
     var $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
     if ($rootScope.user) {
       $state.go("app.homePage");
     } else {
       $state.go("app.loginPage");
     }
});
```

Comment: it gives me a $urlRouterProvider is not defined error even after i try  to include it in the .run(function($urlRouterProvider).....

Comment: proabably need to add it in the config `app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){`

Comment: that still didn't solve my issue :/ Same issue still exits

Comment: well the `$routeChangeStart` is probably the best place to add it

Comment: I get a maximum calls exceeded with that, and e.preventDefault() doesn't help